# Java replaceAll method return null when no match

Tags: java, regex

I have some existing Java code

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(regexStr, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);        
Matcher m = regex.matcher(value);
String replace= m.replaceAll(regexReplaceStr);
```

This is hard-coded in my project.I can't change it. I can only set values `regexStr` and `regexReplaceStr` by configuration. What I need to do is

- If there is a match, return the original string
- If there is no match, return an empty string

What should my strings `regexStr` and `regexReplaceStr` be in this case?

So for example, I have

```
regexStr = "^[^_]+_(.*)$"
regexReplace = "$0"
```

So now if the input string is `AA_BBB`, the value returned is `AA_BBB`. Now, if the input string is `AABBB`, I want it to return an **empty string**. How can this be done?

Comment: For me it seems that, with such **strict limitations**, it is **not possible** to achieve what you want. Your `regexReplace` can not react to the condition. You can't tell it to replace by the match one time and by `""` the other time.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the code is unclear. There is no reference to 'value'...

```
Matcher m = regex.matcher(value);
                           ^ ^
```

And there is also no context about this piece of code.
Is it used as a method? A user input?

You could add this after your code:

```
if (replace == null) {
    replace = "";
}
```

It would then replace null by an empty String.

However I did the same code as you but it never returned null...